# Help with ORA-00933 error

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

If I run the following statement as part of a sql script

```
-- create the pivot_sales_data table
CREATE TABLE pivot_sales_data AS
  SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT month, prd_type_id, amount
   FROM all_sales
   WHERE year = 2003
   AND prd_type_id IN (1, 2, 3)
  )
  PIVOT (
   SUM(amount) FOR month IN (1 AS JAN, 2 AS FEB, 3 AS MAR, 4 AS APR)
  )
  ORDER BY prd_type_id;
```

I get the ORA-00933: SQL Command nor properly ended error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pivot doesn't really work. I'm specifically thinking about:

```
FOR month IN (1 AS JAN, 2 AS FEB, 3 AS MAR, 4 AS APR)
```

In doesn't really work that way. You either want:

```
FOR month IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR')
-- or
FOR month IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Both of these did not work. I am using 10g XE and the code sample is for 11g. Probably some syntax is incorrect for 10g?

Comment: PIVOT is something which was not available until 11.

Comment: Thanks. I commented that part as it is not supported in 10g.